# Can I continue reading from Kindle on PC

Tags: ebook, kindle

Is it possible to read a *progressing* book (pdf) I started on Kindle, on PC?
I would like to realize this scenario: Read book on Kindle. Connect

1. Kindle to PC/Software and pick up where I stopped reading.
2. Disconnect Kindle from software and continue on Kindle where stopped in software.
3. Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Kindle Cloud Reader](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN3p7Zr7PMAhXCVxQKHWcgBfgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fkindle-cloud-reader%2Ficdipabjmbhpdkjaihfjoikhjjeneebd&usg=AFQjCNECM7z2g2HPlyEV-WTXq5OaDswsfw&sig2=mM0Nl2JAego3-xXjg99_MA&bvm=bv.120853415,d.d24) in Chrome. You will need to enable wifi or data connection on the Kindle so it will make a "cloudsync" that let the Kindle extension in Chrome to stay in sync.

Comment: The Kindle PC app works perfectly fine and does this too.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am talking about sideloaded books.

Comment: @Saphire please edit your question with the new information, this way it will pop again to the top of questions and might attract more attention.

Comment: @Saphire Amazon doesn't synchronize books sideloaded to Amazon devices.